# Filipino on a UK marriage visa, going home with spouse for a holiday. What documents do we need to leave the Philippines after our stay?

Tags: visas, uk, filipino-citizens

A Filipino on a UK marriage visa is looking to travel back to the Philippines for a 2-week holiday and to take his spouse to meet the family. When leaving the Philippines, we are worried they may want lots of documents. Has anyone else been in this situation? Could you advise? Do we need to have a minimum amount of time left on the visa? Do we need our marriage certificate?

We also want to bring his Filipino mother back with us for a holiday to the UK for a few months on a visit visa. Is the visit visa the best option, or is there a better one? Also it's her first time to leave the country. Has anyone experienced this and can they give advice on what we might need to do?

Comment: Just a clarification - are you really concerned with *leaving the Philippines*, or is it *re-entry to the UK* after leaving the Philippines which worries you? Unless there's something peculiar about the Philippines I can't see they'd want lots of documentation before allowing you to leave.

Comment: The visitor visa question should be asked separately, but yes, that's the right visa for a family visit of up to six months' duration.

Comment: For clarity, by ‘UK marriage visa’ do you mean a Marriage Visitor visa or a Family visa?

Comment: @brhans the Philippines has departure requirements for citizens.

Answer (score 2):

The only Philippines citizens who face scrutiny while entering / leaving the Philippines are FDH, Foreign Domestic Helpers, aka maids, because (officially, at least) they are often people with a lower education background, and are more at risk to scams etc. So, when leaving, they may face interrogation about their contract, papers, etc.

In reality, they are mostly at risk from the Immigration and Customs officials, who regularly prey on them, especially on returning people, flush with hard-earned cash, and try to extract bribes from them. Indeed because they are at the mercy of the authorities.

A Filipino citizen with his foreign spouse will be on much safer grounds, being both male and with a foreigner. There's no 100% bullet-proof guarantee, but that's a much better situation than the FDH have.

The only document I can think of that officials, and the airline, may ask for on departure is a visa to the UK – which he has. Same goes for his mother. As for her visa, I have little experience with UK visas, other people here will have better knowledge.

Comment: This isn't correct. Filipino citizens with different visas have different exit requirements, and many non-domestic helpers do face scrutiny at exit immigration. Some are even denied boarding.